# create sns mobile application for push notification through cdk

Tags: apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

I am trying to use Amazon's SNS service to send push notifications to iOS devices. Although I have found a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@thabodavidnyakalloklass/ios-push-with-amazons-aws-simple-notifications-service-sns-and-swift-made-easy-51d6c79bc206) that explains how it could be through the AWS console, I would like to achieve the same thing through the CDK since all the infrastructure is defined through there.

Unfortunately, there is nothing resembling an SNS Mobile Application in the cdk [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-sns-readme.html). Does this mean that such an operation is not yet supported by the cdk or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you found any solutions to do this? How about AWS SDK to script it?

Comment: No I gave up on doing it through cdk. But in case you are using cdk v2, it might be worth checking the docs as they might have added it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is that it is not supported in CloudFormation as yet and  CDK is an extension of CloudFormation Templates. If you check the CloudFormation docs for [SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SNS.html) you will see only there is only Subscription, Topic and TopicPolicy present. It would need to be added to CloudFormation first before it can be supported by the CDK.